# Python - networkx.read_pajek not working

Tags: python, macos, graph, matplotlib, networkx

I am working with python networkx and matplotlib.pyplot.

The code I am using is the following:

```
 import networkx as net
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

   orgchart = net.read_pajek("ACME_orgchart.net")
   net.draw(orgchart)
```

The code does not throw errors and runs fine but the graph that is supposed to appear, does not and I know the code runs fine because an icon appears in the dock which I am sure signifies the graph visualization software in python but the actual visualization does not appear . This code is from the book "Social network analysis for startups" if someone could please help me figure this problem out I would be really grateful.

I am using python 2.7.3, on mac osX, with networkx, matplotlib, numpy installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my matplotlib was not being used in interactive mode. Hence when working with an interactive display I needed to also include the line: `plot.show()` at the end for the display to appear.

Further Information can be found at : http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html